# scope/yscale not transforming coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

To my understanding of the documentation, the `scope` block should transform all coordinates. However, in the following example, only circles themselves are scaled, but not their centers: black circles are without `yscale`, red ones are with `yscale=.5`, and are centered at the same points `(a)`, `(b)`:

[image: rendering of the pdf]

What is the problem? Am I misunderstanding the docs?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0,1);
        \draw (a) circle (.5);
        \draw (b) circle (.5);
        \begin{scope}[red,yscale=.5]
            \draw (a) circle (.5);
            \draw (b) circle (.5);
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's normal : `(a)` and `(b)` are defined before the scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Altermundus has already commented, the nodes are defined *before* the scope. When you are saying `(a)` it references an actual node, that has a position. Therefore the transformation matrix is not applied to it, that would basically mean the node would have to be moved. The transformation matrix is applied to *newly created* coordinates. If you were to create the nodes inside of the scope and then refer to them outside of the scope, they would not be moved either.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the transformation in the node reference to change node coordinates:

```
\draw ([yscale=.5] a) circle (.5);
```