# Why such rotate in tikz doesn't work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw=black, anchor=south west] (label) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=300mm]{th.jpg}};
\coordinate (ZX) at (157mm,104mm);
\coordinate (YB) at (249mm,39mm);
\coordinate (YY) at ($(ZX)!1.5!(YB)$);
\coordinate (ZZ) at ($(YB)!2.5!(ZX)$);
\draw[blue!20,very thick] (ZZ)--(YY);
\draw[red!20,very thick, rotate around={90:(ZX)}] (157mm,104mm)--(249mm,39mm);%It works
\draw[red!20,very thick, rotate around={-90:(ZX)}] (ZX)--(YB);%It doesn't work
\filldraw[white] (ZX) circle (2mm);
\filldraw[white] (YB) circle (2mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

a working example

```
     \documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{0}

 \coordinate (O) at (1,1,1);

 %these 2 lines overlap
\draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,.5,0);
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (O) -- (0,.5,0);

 %these 2 lines dont overlap
\draw[thick,->] (1,1,1) -- (0,.5,0);
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (1,1,1) -- (0,.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Transformations are applied only to coordinates...

Comment: You can remove the `\includegraphics`, which is not required to show the problem and prevents the compilation of your code (since we don't have the `jpg`). Also, add the minimal preamble to transform that code into a MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always preferable to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you.

Comment: We've had similar questions before.  Paul Gaborit's comment is spot on.  For more, I recommend reading http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38501/86, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98924/86, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1537/86 (note the quote from the manual in Caramdir's answer there).

Answer (score 7):

In TikZ/pgf, transformations are applied only to numeric coordinates. You can retrieve original numeric coordinates (*only 2D*) from nodes or coordinates via a `let` operation:

```
\draw[red,very thick] let \p1=(ZX),\p2=(YB) in
[rotate around={-90:(ZX)}] (\p1)--(\p2);
```

A complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=black, anchor=south west] (label) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=300mm]{example-image}};
  \coordinate (ZX) at (157mm,104mm);
  \coordinate (YB) at (249mm,39mm);
  \coordinate (YY) at ($(ZX)!1.5!(YB)$);
  \coordinate (ZZ) at ($(YB)!2.5!(ZX)$);
  \draw[blue!20,very thick] (ZZ)--(YY);
  \draw[red!20,very thick, rotate around={90:(ZX)}]
  (157mm,104mm)--(249mm,39mm);%It works

  \draw[red,very thick] let \p1=(ZX),\p2=(YB) in
  [rotate around={-90:(ZX)}] (\p1)--(\p2);
  \filldraw[white] (ZX) circle (2mm);
  \filldraw[white] (YB) circle (2mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** This method can't work with 3D coordinates and 3D transformations since `node` and `coordinate` stores the 2D projections.