# TikZ rotating coordinate problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, coordinates

I am trying to rotate point `(B0)` by 90 degrees ccw around `(A1)` and then loop it to get `(B\k)` and `(A\k)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B0) at (0,1);
\path[draw,blue](A0)--(B0)coordinate[pos=.382](A1);
\coordinate(B1)at([rotate around={90:(A1)}]B0);
\draw[red](A1)--(B1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red is what I get, green is what I excpect]

red is what I get using

```
([rotate around={90:(A1)}]B0)
```

and green is what I would like to see.

Comment: hint--> play around with scale value

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
\node (A) at (A0) {A};
\coordinate (B) at (0,1);
    \foreach \k in {0,90,180,270}
    {
        \node (B\k) at ([rotate around={\k:(A0)}]B) {B\k};;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pic]

Comment: Not exactly. The centres for rotations in a loop will be succesive A\j. But his is not the issue yet. The problem is that B1 is not where I want it to be.

Comment: Shall it look like using `\draw[red](A1)--([rotate around={90:(A1)}]B0);` ?

Comment: Still what I get by  ([rotate around={90:(A1)}]B0)  is sth like (1,2), but I want (-.618,.382)

Comment: @Konne In your example, change `(0,0)` by `(1,0)` to see the problem of your answer...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the source of your problem is scaling. It scales coordinates of center of rotation twice. Once when you define (A1), second for rotation (you can see this by explicit notation {90:(0,1.91)})

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{subj} = [circle, minimum width=0.2mm, draw,inner sep=1mm]
\coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B0) at (0,5);
\path[draw,blue](A0)--(B0) coordinate[pos=.382](A1);
\coordinate(B1)at ([rotate around={90:(A1)}]B0);
\draw[red](A1)--(B1);
\node[subj] at (A0) {A0};
\node[subj] at (B1) {B1};
\node[subj] at (B0) {B0};
\node[subj] at (A1) {A1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right. `B1` moves while I change `scale`. But I want the picture scaled. Hence there seem to be 2 solutions: change scale by adjusting `A0` or do this `\p` trick to enable perform normal scaling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. That question helped a lot:

[Why such rotate in tikz doesn't work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95030/why-such-rotate-in-tikz-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Now my code enriched with loop is like this and works perfectly:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,intersections,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
%
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15]
\coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B0) at (0,1);
\draw[blue](A0)--(B0);
\foreach \k[evaluate={\ki=int(\k-1)}] in {1,...,7}
{\path(A\ki)--(B\ki)coordinate[pos=.382](A\k);
\draw[red] let \p\ki=(A\ki), \p\k=(A\k) in (\p\k)--([rotate around={90:(\p\k)}]B\ki)coordinate(B\k);
\node[draw] at (B\k){B\k};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```