# TikZ: Problem when using shift and rotate

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I am having an issue when I use `shift` and `rotate`.  In one case, the rectangle is being elongated down to the stopping point of the shift and rotate.

However, if I issue the same command in another case, the rectangle acts in the appropriate manner by rotating and shifting not elongating to the stopping point.

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \filldraw[outer color = blue!75!pink!60,
  inner color = red!50!black!20, rotate = {-30}, shift = {(2, 0)}] (O) rectangle
  (.75, .5);

  \filldraw[red] (3, 0) rectangle (4, .75);
  \filldraw[red, rotate = {45}, shift = {(1, 0)}] (3, 0) rectangle (4, .75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the elongated rectangle to behave as the red rectangle.  When I issue a `rotate` and `shift`, I want the rectangle to do just that not stretch to the spot.

This stretching only occurs with objects placed at the origin.

Comment: shift is not moving the object, it is adding the shift amount to all explicit coordinates on the path. (O) is not an explicit coordinate.

Comment: @percusse why isn't that occurring when the object isn't at the origin?

Comment: @dustin: It doesn't have anything to do with being at the origin or not, it's using a node `(O)` that causes the problem, because nodes aren't transformed. You can either use `(0,0)` instead of `(O)`, or you can apply the transformation to the node explicitly using `\filldraw[outer color = blue!75!pink!60,
  inner color = red!50!black!20, rotate = {-30}, shift = {(2, 0)}] ([rotate = {-30}, shift = {(2, 0)}]O) rectangle
  (.75, .5);`

Comment: @Jake are you going to post your answer?

Comment: Related question is [Transform defined coordinates in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98924) where a few solutions are posted.

Answer (score 1):

The transformations are not commutative. Consider the examples below;

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (3,3);
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\fill[red,shift={(1,0)}] (A) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[blue,rotate=45,shift={(1,0)}] (A) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[yellow,shift={(1,0)},rotate=45] (A) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[orange,rotate=45] (A) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the last orange box, `(2,2)` is rotated and becomes vertical but `(A)` doesn't. That's because `(1,1)` is still at the original place. It is the difference in a nutshell between coordinate transformations and canvas transformations.

This is one of the reasons why I stick to lower level PGF versions of transformations. Otherwise if you want to operate on the coordinate itself Jake's comment is the way to go.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the non-commutativeness (is that even a word?), but the fact that the node `(A)` isn't shifted, unlike the `(2,2)` coordinate, which causes the stretching in dustin's code. Try replacing the `(A)`s with `(1,1)` in your code to see the difference.

Comment: @Jake Kind of. `(A)` is a fixed point in the canvas and the tranformations apply to coordinate calculations that uses `\pgfvecx` etc. so they are parsed. `(A)` doesn't get parsed but referred to. Was that a proper sentence?