# coordinates and transformations

Tags: tikz-pgf

The `\pgfgetlastxy` syntax does not seem to yield the right results for `coordinates` when some coordinate transformation is applied to the `tikzpicture`.

Yet everything is right for `node`s, or when we `draw` the `coordinate`.

Is this the same issue as in [Transform defined coordinates in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98924/transform-defined-coordinates-in-tikz) ?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    scale=.5,
    %cm={.5,0,0,.5,(0,0)}, %also changes the measurement
    %xslant=2, 
    %transform canvas= %fixes the measurement discrepancy
    %{
    %  scale=.5,
    %},
  ]

  \coordinate 
  [
    label=a,
    %circle, draw, %fixes the measurement discrepancy
  ]
  (a) at (1,1);
  \path (a);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\lastX}{\lastY}
  \node [anchor=north]at (0,0) {\verb|\lastX| for the coordinate : \lastX};

  \node 
  [
    label=b, 
    inner sep=0pt, 
    outer sep=0pt, 
    minimum height=0pt,
  ] (b) at (1,1){};
  \path (b);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\lastX}{\lastY}
  \node [anchor=south]at (0,0) {\verb|\lastX| for the node : \lastX};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use `\path (b.center);` rather then `\path (b);`

Comment: OTOH `\draw (\lastX,\lastY) -- (0,0);` works better with (b) than (a) or (b.center).

Answer (score 1):

Such PGF command is just a short cut to the internal dimension register `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`. The definition is simpler than you think

> ```
> \def\pgfgetlastxy#1#2{%
>   \edef#1{\the\pgf@x}%
>   \edef#2{\the\pgf@y}%
> }%
> ```

That is, since all advanced calculations are done by `\pgf@x`/`\pgf@y`/`\pgf@xa`/etc, there is no guarantee that `\pgf@x` is really what you want, specially in Ti*k*Z. For Ti*k*Z, there are `\tikz@lastx` and `\tikz@lastxsaved`.

By the way, as @Salim Bou mentioned, `(b.center)` is a coordinate and `(b)` is not.

When you write `\path(b)circle(0);`, Ti*k*Z will take the node seriously because it wants to know where to draw the circle. In this case the result is `14...pt` (0.5cm). In this case, what actually happens is something like `\path(b.center)circle(0);`. But when you write only `\path(b);`, Ti*k*Z simply has nothing to do and `\pgf@x` can be anything.

(when you write `\path(5,5)--(b);`, Ti*k*Z will find a point on the border of `(b)` and on point on the border of (c). I expect that the result is the x-coordinate of the point on the border. However this calculation might be done in a group so you cannot see `\pgf@x` changing.)