# Coordinates in tikz can't be scaled

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following example should show a square and a smaller copy of it inside, the commands `xscale` and `yscale`  work when I write the coordinates manually on both paths, but when I reference the coordinates defined previously, it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (1,1);
\coordinate (C) at (1,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (-1,-1);
\draw (A) to (B) to (C) to (D) to cycle;
\draw[xscale=0.5,yscale=0.5] (A) to (B) to (C) to (D) to cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This image shows the expected versus the obtained figure.

[image]

**EDIT**: Apparently I forgot to explicit my question, how to properly get this done? Apply scalings, or any transformation in general, to previously defined coordinates?

Comment: You can check [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98924).

Comment: Thanks, that question seems to provide appropriate answers.

Comment: Of course, you can scale the (named) coordinates with the calc library (`\usetikzlibrary{calc}`) : `\draw ($0.5*(A)$) to ($0.5*(B)$) to ($0.5*(C)$) to ($0.5*(D)$) to cycle;` or shorter `\draw ($0.5*(A)$) rectangle ($0.5*(C)$);`.

Comment: @marmot you don't need `calc` for this `([scale=.5]A)` works.

Comment: @Kpym Cool. Didn't know that! Good to know. I think you should answer that question, then. And merci!

Comment: @Kpym Arguably even simpler: `\draw[transform canvas={xscale=0.5,yscale=0.5}] (A) to (B) to (C) to (D) to cycle;` This should also work [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98924/transform-defined-coordinates-in-tikz).

Comment: @marmot simpler, may be, but not equivalent, as you know. If you really want a global style, check [this Mark Wibrow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98961).

Comment: @Kpym I know, but depending on the needs `transform canvas` may be OK or even better than the other solution. (I upvoted both your and Mark's answer... )