# How can one use named coordinates and still do the coordinate transformations (`shift`, `rotate` etc.)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, transformation

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [help lines, step=1cm] (0,0) grid (4,2); 
    \coordinate[label={$X$}] (X) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label={$Y$}] (Y) at (4,0);
    \draw[thick, red, yshift=2cm]  (0,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[thick, blue, yshift=2cm]  (X)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex` produces this image:

[image]

Why isn't the blue line over the red one (as I would expect)? The only difference between them is that the blue line uses the named versions of the coordinates. I tried googling this and read the pgfmanual, but couldn't find the answer (could not find an example with named coordinates).

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98924/86, does that help?

Comment: You have to shift named coordinates as individually, like `\draw[thick, blue, ]  ([yshift=2cm]X)--([yshift=2cm]Y);`

Answer (score 2):

So you can shift every `coordinate` like Andrew proposed in his comment, or you can also use `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [help lines, step=1cm] (0,0) grid (4,2); 
    \coordinate[label={$X$}] (X) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label={$Y$}] (Y) at (4,0);
    \draw[thick,orange, yshift=2cm]  (0,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[very thick, blue, dashed]  ($(X)+(0,2)$) -- ($(Y)+(0,2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

[image: shift nodes with calc]